# Limit of derivative is zero. Does it imply a limit for f(x)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have come across the following question:

> Say $f(x): [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable.
>
> Given $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f'(x) = 0$, does this imply an existence of a limit (finite or not) of $f$ at infinity?

From what I tried to do, looking at the definition of the derivative:

$\lim_{\substack{h\rightarrow0 \\ x\rightarrow\infty}}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = 0$
you could say that $\lim_{\substack{h\rightarrow0 \\ x\rightarrow\infty}} f(x+h) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$. Is it enough to prove the existence of a limit?

if not, is there another way to prove or disprove that?

Comment: We're *given* the existence of a derivative. What you say is enough to prove that f is continuous

Comment: @E.Z. Your question asks one thing, your efforts try to prove another.. what do you want exactly?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I made a type error. Not the "existence of the derivative", but the "existence of the limit".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider $f(x)=\sin(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed.